# How to convert ranged touch/target spells into melee touch attack spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, ranged-attack, touch-attacks

Duskblades of 13th level or higher gain the ability to channel a touch-range spell they know into their weapon, and make a full attack with it. However, they know very few touch-range spells!

The duskblade spell list has many cool *rays* though, like *disintegrate*, or targeted spells like *slashing dispel*. I would like to be able to channel these spells into my weapon, and stab many enemies with them as part of a full attack.

The method needs to be achievable for a character whose first 13 levels are in duskblade. I already know about enlightened fist's Hold Ray, but I am hoping there is an option that doesn't lock in all 20 of my levels.

I'm open to Dragon Magazine and perhaps even 3rd party sources, but Pathfinder is off the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a 3rd party source, may I suggest making a slight alteration to the existing feat Reach Spell and convert it into a new feat named "Close Spell". Which basically is a feat that does the opposite of what you are asking for. If Dragon Magazine is legal, I couldn't imagine that a feat like this would cause any qualms with the group/DM.

> #### Close Spell [Metamagic]
>
> You can cast ranged touch spells by touching the spell recipient.
> You may cast a spell that normally has a range of "close", "medium", or "long" at touching distance. The spell effectively becomes a touch attach, so you must succeed at a touch attack to bestow the spell upon the recipient. A close spell uses up a spell slot two [should probably be one instead of two here IMO] levels higher than the spell's actual level.

Comment: Please do not use code formatting for non-code text. See [meta discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3057/4563). I also removed the quote of Reach Spell, since it didn’t seem necessary to the answer, though you can feel free to add it back if you like. You may prefer to link to the [SRD version of the feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#reachSpell) rather than reference *Faiths & Pantheons* though.

Comment: It seems to me like the feat should probably interact with saving throws in some way or else be a +0 LA metamagic.  How did it work when you tested it?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer it worked out pretty well, scorching ray became a nuisance though, I used  a +1 mod myself and everything worked out well.

Answer (score -2):

The prestige class The Ordained Champion from Complete Champion from complete champion has an ability called chanel spell it's not quite what you're looking for but it reads

> Channel Spell (Sp): At 3rd level, you can channel any spell available to you that has one creature or more as its target into your melee weapon. Doing so requires a move action and uses up a spell slot or a prepared spell of casting time no greater than one standard action. The channeled spell affects the next target you successfully attack with that weapon, though saving throws and spell resistance still apply normally. Even if the spell normally affects an area or is a ray, it still affects only the target in this case. On a successful hit, the spell is discharged from the weapon, which can then hold another spell. You can channel your spells into only one weapon at a time. A spell channeled into a weapon is lost if not used within 8 hours.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, I felt that I must downvote this answer—it does not answer the question posed. The ordained champion’s channel spell (as well as similar features from a variety of classes) are not compatible with the duskblade’s arcane channeling, which is the point of the question. That could be clearer in the question, but ultimately it’s usually necessary to be familiar with the material being asked about in order to answer.